# How to calculate coefficient of drag for a particular shape?

Tags: aircraft-design, drag

While working on my project I gave my RC plane's nose a particular shape. It doesn't resemble any simple shapes for which coefficient of drag is provided on Internet. 
I don't know simulations.  Also I don't have any wind tunnel facility for my project.  So is there any other way,  any website or any formula for computing coefficient of lift and drag?

Comment: Search for computational fluid dynamics (CFD).  I think there are open source programs that run on a PC.  Not a simple task, though.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what you plan to do with the coefficient?

Comment: I don't know simulations on any software.  I also don't have much time to learn simulations.

Answer (score 3):

There are essentially only two ways to do this.

First you can build a wind tunnel, run experiments and measure the forces involved.

The second is to run a computer simulation. There is software that will do this, but it is complex professional grade engineering software. Free applications are available, but I can't vouch for their effectiveness. You can search for "computational fluid dynamics software" to find options. Adding "free" to that will find you a few cost-free options.

Be aware that setting up and using this software is a complex task that involves creating a CAD model of your shape. You can definitely do the calculation if you are interested, but it's not a simple or quick task.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want answer, use wind tunnel. If you want to *calculate* the answer, you must solve [Navier-Stokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) equations, with boundary conditions established to represent the shape in question. This is done using [numerical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) and is an advanced mathematical process involving complex analysis (by which I mean meaning using [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) and [complex functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex-valued_function)).

As mentioned in another answer, there is software available that does much of this for you.